# Linux kernel support for USB gamepads?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb

I've got an old Logitech USB gamepad that worked well under both Windows and Mac OS X. That is, the gamepad was totally "plug and play" for games run by a Super Nintendo emulator (SNES9X).
Does Linux support such gamepads out of the box? Or any other controller for that matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - they're recognised as an input device and you should be able to see information about it with "lsusb".